# popup with angular 7

Tags: angular, primeng

I have the follwing code which work great, it show some simple data with table when press a button, But I want all the data of table to show with popup window and not part of the screen, how can I do it nicely? Thanks

```
<button pButton
        type="button"
        [disabled]="this.data == null"
        icon="pi pi-angle-down"
        (click)='toggleShowTable()'
        iconPos="left"
        label="versions"
        class="ui-button-rounded ui-button-secondary"></button>
<div *ngIf="data">
  
  <p-table *ngIf='showTable' [columns]="cols" [value]="data">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
      <tr>
        <th class="ui-column-title" *ngFor="let col of columns">
          {{col.header}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data let-columns="columns">
      <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
          <div class="p-column-text">{{data[col.field]}}</div>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PrimeNG has the dialog to support this:

app.component.html:

```
<p-dialog 
   [(visible)]="display"
   [showHeader]="false"
   [dismissableMask]="true"
   [modal]="true" 
   [contentStyle]="{'max-height':'200px'}">
   <p> content </p>
</p-dialog>

<button type="button" (click)="showDialog()" icon="pi pi-info-circle" label="Show"></button>
```

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
    display: boolean = false;

    showDialog() {
        this.display = true;
    }
}
```

The content can be styled with contentStyle attribute, Header can be hidden via showHeader attribute and clicking in outside of the dialog will close it due to the dismissableMask attribute.

Other attributes can be found in the excellent documentation at: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v7-lts/#/dialog

Comment: Thank you very much! maybe you know how can I stick the design of the content to the dialog ? and how can I remove the title and the frame of the dialog? and last question - how can I do that when the user press out the dialod the dialog is closing?

Comment: You can adapt the design via  CSS, like with everything else. The rest should all be explained by reading the documentation that was linked.

Comment: I've updated the answer for the questions in the comment, as @cloned suggests: please scroll down to the documentation of the attributes.

Comment: @cloned @CharlieV I used ` [dismissableMask]="true" [closeOnEscape]="true"` but when pressing out the dialog it not gone. why can it be? thanks

Comment: I should have added ```[modal]="true"```; that will make it work @bob2habanay

Comment: @CharlieV thank you so much! your'e great! my last question after using  `[modal]="true"` - can I stick the dialog to the button that show him? not in the middle of the screen? and it make all the other elements on screen darker - can I cancel it? many thanks!

Comment: Your requirement can be met by using an [overlay panel](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v7-lts/#/overlaypanel) or by using the appendTo attribute. To make the other elements darker you can use **maskStyleClass** attribute

Comment: dismissableMask doesn't change anything for me. I want all the screen look the same after clicking. `overlay panel ` needs big change for me? Thank you!! @CharlieV

Comment: The OverlayPanel is a small change (IMHO). The dismissableMask can be used to style the background AFAIK.